# Cucumber @before and @after hooks usage

Tags: automation, cucumber, bdd

I am designing a BDD automation framework, where we are thinking of using cucumber @Before and @after hooks, can anyone suggest the best use of these?

Comment: What context are you planning to use the hooks for?

Comment: Context means?, I am having cucumber BDD framework with Java code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different hooks for before and after,

BeforeFeature:- Automation logic that has to run before each feature. Say in the feature file you have 10 scenarios, then for each 10 scenarios, BeforeFeature would be common. One use case is, say you want to get a global variable from config which is using by all scenarios in a feature. In this case, you don't need to go and get it during each scenario. Create a BeforeFeature hook

BeforeScenario:- Run before each scenario. Say you have 10 scenarios and you want to run one step which is common to all 10 scenarios. In this case, you can create a BeforeScenario hook. One example is, say you want to create a REST client and that REST client is common for all 10 scenarios. Go for BeforeScenario hook then.

AfterFeature:- Say if you want to clean up something, which was common to all feature then clean it in AfterFeature. This will run only after the completion of all scenarios in a feature.

AfterScenario:- Run after each scenario. If you want to clean up something after each scenario. say if you want to dispose of the REST client you have created during BeforeScenario then you can do that here.

Please find full hooks,

[image]